# How to find which version of node is used/considered by pnpm? (related to ERR_PNPM_UNSUPPORTED_ENGINE)

Tags: node.js, pnpm

I run `pnpm install` and got this error:

```
$ pnpm install
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
 ERR_PNPM_UNSUPPORTED_ENGINE  Unsupported environment (bad pnpm and/or Node.js version)

Your Node version is incompatible with "/dependency-cruiser/16.0.0".

Expected version: ^18.17||>=20
Got: v18.5.0

This is happening because the package's manifest has an engines.node field specified.
To fix this issue, install the required Node version.
```

I can't find where the version 18.5.0 came from (related to **Got: v18.5.0**). That version is not installed. In my opinion, I satisfy that criteria with my actual node version (v20.10.0, see below).

I'm on Windows 10, with Git Bash. I have installed pnpm with PowerShell command `iwr https://get.pnpm.io/install.ps1 -useb | iex`.

Here are versions of pnpm and node:

```
// actual version of pnpm
$ pnpm --version
8.14.1

// actual node's version
$ node --version
v20.10.0

// all my node's versions:
$ pnpm env list
  18.19.0
* 20.10.0
  21.6.0
```

Could it be that a package need 18.5, and this is what **Got** is using? Because my first impression is that **Got** is detected by the `node --vesion` in use. But, it could hardly be that, because 18.5 is not installed.

EDIT:
Strangely, if I remove the lock file, it works, but the next `pnpm install` command fails with error shown above.

```
$ rm pnpm-lock.yaml 
$ pnpm install
Already up to date
Progress: resolved 430, reused 407, downloaded 0, added 0, done
Done in 18.4s
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Windows 10 wsl distribution Ubuntu-22.04.

I use nvm with node v18.19.0.

I solved this by [uninstalling pnpm](https://pnpm.io/uninstall) which I installed using a standalone script (`iwr` your case `curl` my case) and installing with `npm install -g pnpm`.

Hope this helps.